# How to safely recreate a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a few tables on my PostgreSQL server that take a lot more disk space than they should. I know that a full vacuum would reclaim the space, but full vacuum puts an exclusive lock on the table and these tables get constantly written to and full vacuum would cause too much disruption of service (one of the tables uses over a terabyte of extra space). so I have come up with the following function to re-create a table without locking it.

```
create or replace function recreate_table(t text) returns void as $$
declare
    new_name text;
    old_name text;
    seq_name text;
    tab regclass;
begin
    new_name := 'new_' || t;
    old_name := 'old_' || t;
    seq_name := t || '_id_seq';
    execute format('create table %I (like %I including all)', new_name, t);
    execute format('alter table %I rename to %I', t, old_name);
    execute format('alter table %I rename to %I', new_name, t);
    execute format('alter sequence %I owned by %I.id', seq_name, t);
    execute format('insert into %I select * from %I', t, old_name);
    --- execute format('drop table %I', old_name);
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It seems to work as expected, but I wonder how safe this is. Are there any problems with this approach that I am not seeing?

Note: I am using insert because the tables in question contain log data, so they are constantly appended to, but existing records never change. To do it properly, I would use some combination of insert and update, but my postgres is 9.4 and doesn't support upserts and using inserts is good enough for my purpose.

Update: looks like `alter table` exclusively locks the table and the lock persists until the function is done, so the table stays lock while inserts are executed. Also, apparently PostgreSQL does not natively support commits inside a function. There is a workaround for this using dlink API. Need to figure out how to use it to do a commit between table renames and the insert.

Comment: `alter table ... rename to ...` uses an `access exclusive` lock so there shouldn't be big differences in the availability of the table between your function and `vacuum full`.

Comment: Yeah, just figured it out in my testing. Looking to separate the renames and inserts into separate transactions

Comment: Performing these two operations in separate transactions can result in data loss.

Comment: Not sure how. I will do the table create, renames and sequence ownership change. Commit. Now the writes can go into the new, empty table, but the sequence stays put, so the new record PKs will not clash with the existing data. Then I can insert records from the old table into the new one. Where do I lose data?

Comment: Inserts from the old table will compete with regular inserts. This may raise conflicts in the primary key.

Comment: Hmm... but the data from the old table already has defined primary keys (these are all serial fields, I don't have any tricky PKs). And since I am not recreating the sequence, I expect it to retain its current value, so any new inserts will get PKs higher than the existing records. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Seems a bit risky, but indeed, if the serial pk is the only unique constraint this should work, as the inserts of the old rows don't touch the sequence.

Comment: As I mentioned, these tables contain log data, so in my specific case, I think I should be safe. But I agree that this is dangerous as a more general approach.